# Avatar and screen name. How can I change it?

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

I uploaded a GIF and set a screen name for my profile. It  didn't change anything.

Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

You go here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/14593406

make the changes you want, and then click the big, blue "Save" button.

My crystal ball says that you forgot to click the big, blue "Save" button after making changes.

Comment: Does Stack Overflow support animated GIFs in profile pictures? If not, is it possible OP clicked "Save" and the site just said, "No, you can't do that"?

Comment: As far as I know, @F1Krazy, you can select an animated GIF, but only the first frame will be shown. But... I haven't actually tried it. What good are animated glasses, after all?